# median test in python for arrays with different length

Tags: python, median

Need to a a median test for 4 arrays which are of quite different length.

```
from scipy.stats import median_test
stat, p, med, tbl = median_test(a[0], a[1], a[2],a[3])

results:
stat 3.228017883755589  p 0.35778751941884523  med  0.00873917447505705
tbl 
 [[28 21  7  2]
 [33 21  4  0]]
```

The p-value is too high to reject the null hypothesis. From boxplot the medians are quite different.
Is there a more robust way to do median test considering sample size?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Kruskal-Wallis H-test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kruskal.html)? It should do fine for larger samples as well. Consider that the Kruskal-Wallis H-test assumes

> that the variance is approximately equal across samples

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_test)

Comment: according to this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16219/testing-the-difference-of-some-quantile-q-between-groups    Kruskal-Wallis test is not for median.